# Need a Shutdown script: Check date if Wednesday run batch script

Tags: windows, vbscript, batch-file, shutdown

We use avast adnm 4.8 and it has no shutdown scanning option.
 I have made a batch script to run Avast on shutting down.

```
@echo off
shutwdown -a
pushd "C:\Program Files\Alwil Software\Avast4"

cls

echo --------------------------------------------------------------

echo Bezig met scannen, de computer wordt automatisch uitgezet...

echo --------------------------------------------------------------

aswcmd C: /m /*

popd "C:\Program Files\Alwil Software\Avast4"

shutdown -s
```

But I only want to scan the computers on wednesday. So if its not Wednesday computers must shutdown without scan.

I need a VBscript to check de current date and call the batchscript if it's wednesday andn continue shutdown on other days . I want to use this script as shutdown script. If it is possible with a batch script its also fine.

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick

```
If WeekdayName(Weekday(Date))="Wednesday" Then
 Dim shell
 Set shell=createobject("wscript.shell")
 shell.run "C:\Documents and Settings\Amol\Desktop\Temp\Shutdown.bat"
 set shell=Nothing
End If
```

Comment: Hi 4M01, It is not working. I tried on Dutch and English windows but no luck. For dutch i changed it to "wo" and "woensdag".

Comment: Is there any error you getting, What you have changed ? You just need to change path for your bat file instead of this "C:\Documents and Settings\Amol\Desktop\Temp\Shutdown.bat"

Comment: I have only changed the path for my batch script thats all. I don't get any errors. It doesn't run the batch script. I have used this: If WeekdayName(Weekday(Date))="Wednesday" Then  Dim shell  Set shell=createobject("wscript.shell")  shell.run "C:\Documents and Settings\test\Desktop\Temp\aVastShutdownScan.bat"  set shell=Nothing End If

Comment: """C:\Documents and Settings\test\Desktop\Temp\aVastShutdownScan.bat"""
try this instead of "C:\Documents and Settings\test\Desktop\Temp\aVastShutdownScan.bat"

Comment: Ok i got it working. Changed Wednesday to woensdag (dutch) and it worked. But we have also English Windows so i have changed your script. I will post it as answer below. Thank you very much for your help mate. You are hero !

Answer (score 2):

You may do that with this Batch script:

```
@ECHO OFF
FOR /F "TOKENS=1-3 DELIMS=/" %%A IN ("%DATE%") DO SET /A MM=10%%A %% 100, DD=10%%B %% 100, YY=%%C
IF %MM% LSS 3 SET /A MM+=12, YY-=1
SET /A A=YY/100, B=A/4, C=2-A+B, E=36525*YY/100, F=306*(MM+1)/10, DOW=(C+DD+E+F-3)%%7
IF NOT %DOW% == 3 GOTO SHUTDOWN
ECHO TODAY IS WEDNESDAY, SCAN HERE...
:SHUTDOWN
ECHO SHUTDOWN HERE...
```

The DOW variable have a value between 0 (Sunday) and 6 (Saturday). If your date format is not MM/DD/YYYY, change the MM, DD and YY variables order in the FOR/SET command accordingly.

Comment: @e2e2: Excuse me? It works fine in my machine! Insert `ECHO MM=%MM%, DD=%DD%, YY=%YY%` before `SET /A` command and report the result, please. Is `/` char. your date delimiter? (just type `ECHO %DATE%`). If not, change it in `DELIMS=/`.

Comment: @e2e2: Opps! Insert `ECHO MM=%MM%, DD=%DD%, YY=%YY%` before `IF %MM% LSS 3 ...` and report the result, please... :)

Answer (score 1):

Its always better to compare with Weekday() and only use WeekdayName() for display purposes.

Fortunately there's a global system enum that already maps all of Weekday()'s numeric values to day of the week name constants readable in your Windows installation's local language. I imagine your installation offers a vbWoensdag constant. Otherwise we'd have future programmers going what's the 4 here for?

```
Weekday() will return one of the following constant values:

vbSunday    1
vbMonday    2
vbTuesday   3
vbWednesday 4
vbThursday  5
vbFriday    6
vbSaturday  7
```

The correct way to write the test would be

```
If Weekday(date) = vbWednesday Then ....
```

Also you can always use Now in place of Date. The difference is Now includes the current time of day where Date always zeros that portion of the datetime value. If you look at a datetime variant numerically as a double, the integer portion is the date and the time is the remainder. So Date is basically Int(Now) which is midnight, when that day begins. you can also say Tomorrow = Date + 1 if you find calling DateAdd() for a simple increment excessive.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to [4M01](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1115090/4m01)

1) This script works only on dutch Windows: (change "woensdag" to your own language e.g Wednesday if you use english windows. It is case sensitive)

```
If WeekdayName(Weekday(date)) = "woensdag" Then
 Dim shell
 Set shell=createobject("wscript.shell")
 shell.run """C:\Documents and Settings\test\Desktop\scan.bat"""
 set shell=Nothing
End If
```

2) This script works with multi language Windows. (You have to find the day number of the week. In this case Wednesday was number 4)

```
If Weekday(date) = "4" Then
 Dim shell
 Set shell=createobject("wscript.shell")
 shell.run """C:\Documents and Settings\test\Desktop\scan.bat"""
 set shell=Nothing
End If
```